# How to configure meson for a debug build using -Og?

Tags: meson-build

The universal options for meson gives me build types for debug (the default) with no optimizations, and an optimized debug which uses `-02`.  How do I generate a debug build that uses **`-Og`** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are documented here: https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html

Specifically you want `--optimization=g`.